# Web API Clear Button

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Trying to get a clear button to work for my simple calculator. It should clear three text boxes: the first number (fn), second number (sn), and the total (tn). I am using a web api for this - everything works except for the clear button. I am uncertain on how to write the Clear function correctly - any guidance would be appreciated. I think I am going in the wrong direction with the controller function. Below I listed my HTML, then my Controller, and then my model for just the clear function.

HTML:

'''

```
    function clr() {
    // clear function goes here
         $.ajax({
            url: "/api/calc/clr/" + fn.value + "/" + sn.value,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                tn.value = html
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
     }


</script>


<input type="reset" value="Clear Results" onclick="clr();" />
```

Controller code:

```
    [Route("api/calc/clr/{paramOne}/{paramTwo}")]

    public IHttpActionResult Delete(float paramOne, float paramTwo)
    {
        return oCalc.Clr(paramOne, paramTwo);

    }
```

Model Code:

```
       public float Clr (float fn, float sn)
       {
        return ();

       }
```

'''

Comment: think logically, why should your API care about your front end? you need to decide how this thing is going to work, what do you expect to happen on the API side. Your front end collects data, issues an API call, the API does something, returns a result then you can do whatever you want client side with the result you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call API for any of the client side processing. You can clear out the values using following code

```
<input type="text" id="n1" value="10" />
<input type="text" id="n2" value="20" />

<input type="button" onclick="clr()" />
```

**JavaScript code**

```
<script>
    function clr() {
        // clear function goes here
        $("#n1,#n2").val("");
    }
</script>
```